# Read JavaFx Application

Tags: javafx-8, javafx-2

I created a small javaFx Program. The Program just displays random points. Now I want to get and read the generated Stage from a different class and read the co-ordinates. Is it possible ?
I tried creating a class variable to get stage but its null always.

I added a class variable and assigned the prepared Stage object to the variable. I am then trying to get the Stage object from the variable.

```
public class DCGUI extends Application {
    private Stage primaryStage1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
        Platform.exit();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Random r = new Random(64);

        // List<Integer> points = r.ints(1000, 0, 400).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<Node> cList = new ArrayList<>();
        Line line = null;
        Circle c = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < 50001; i++) {
            //System.out.println(r.nextInt());
            c = new Circle(r.nextInt(400), r.nextInt(400), 0.0125);
            c.setStroke(Color.RED);
            c.setId(i+"");
            cList.add(c);
        }


        Group group = new Group(cList);

        Scene scene = new Scene(group, 400, 400);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Dynamic Connectivity");

        primaryStage1 = primaryStage;
        primaryStage.show();

}
```

Comment: Show what you have tried so far in code

Comment: I added what i tried...Just started JavaFX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume the following code example. By calling the `getMainStage()` method you can have access to your `Stage` object.

*Of course, the `main.fxml` file is binded with the `MainController` class*

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends Application{

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader("path/to/main.fxml").toFile().toURI().toURL());
    MainController.setMainStage(stage); <---- !
    Parent root = loader.load();
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1400, 850));
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}}
```

**MainController.java**

```
public class MainController{
    // fxml view elements...
    private static Stage mainStage;
    //...
    public static Stage getMainStage() {
        return mainStage;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was going the other way and it was always null... Thank you